# YUM package available in repo, but while install gives "No package"

Tags: python-3.6, yum, rhel7, epel

I am upgrading from python 2.7 to 3.6.

We are using JFrog artifactory repository for hosting packages.
I have verified in the yum repo (artifactory) URL that the package python36 exists.

Following are the things tried:

```
In /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo, added the baseurl of yum (artifactory) repo.
yum clean all
yum info python36 - Error: No matching Packages to list
yum install python36 - No package python36 available. Error: Nothing to do
```

But the install respond by saying "No package available".
Please advise if I am missing anything here or need to look into other things.

Comment: `yum repolist`: does your repel repository show up in the list? otherwise it is not active / not working...

Comment: @ChrisMaes yes it was showing the epel in the list. It turns out there was an issue with artifactory, artifacts was not discoverable, now after fix and reload of repo it is working.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For records -
With yum repolist and yum search working, yum install should be working.
It turns out there was an issue with repo and artifacts were not discoverable.
Now after repo being reloaded the things are working fine.

Comment: yeah, looks like it was temporary epel issue. We've switched to our own epel repo copy  because of this issue